# Hover on part of SVG, change path fill

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to change the fill color of a path when I hover over it in an SVG. I can't seem to make it work. I am thinking it is a z-index issue.
I've tried every selector I can think of.
I've changed the order of the paths so they are the last elements in the svg.

I am trying to change the path's with the class .wedge
I've applied a global z-index using:

```
* {z-index: 1;}
```

Then on .wedge I increased the z-index:

```
.wedge {z-index: 10 !important;)
```

That didn't work.
Something I found interesting but not sure if it is relevant, I added a click function to change the fill color of one of the paths. That works and if you click it the hover will start working.

Here is a codepen: 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/west4me/pen/zPrxvB)

Any ideas?

Comment: Just tried that with no success.

Comment: In SVG 1.1 (at least) z-index was not supported on SVG elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be related to the

```
.st4 {
  fill: none;
}
```

Changing that to:

```
.st4 {
  fill: transparent;
}
```

and then using the regular `:hover` class of:

```
.wedge:hover {
  fill: rgba(21, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```

does the trick. Like this:

```css
/*
* === CSS for SVG compass ===
*/


/*
* — Structural and appearance —
*/

* {
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Contains compass and limits its size */

.compassWrap {
  max-width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* probably needs adjusted */


/* SVG styles, no need to change */

.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #505050;
  stroke-width: 4.11;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}


/* don't change */

.st1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #808080;
  stroke-width: 2.57;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}


/* don't change */

.st2 {
  fill: #505050;
}


/* don't change */

.st3 {
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* don't change */

.st4 {
  fill: transparent;
}


/* don't change */


/*
* — Pie color classes —
Add the class to the path with the ID of the direction you want
Available path ID's
#nnwPie - north by north west
#wnwPie - west by north west
#wswPie - west by south west
#sswPie - south by south west
#ssePie - south by south east
#esePie - east by south east
#enePie - east by north east
#nnePie - north by north east
*/

.green {
  fill: rgba(21, 255, 0, 0.5);
}


/* best wind */

.dgreen {
  fill: rgba(12, 140, 0, 0.5);
}


/* less good wind */

.red {
  fill: rgba(255, 42, 0, 0.5);
}


/* worst wind */

.dred {
  fill: rgba(140, 23, 0, 0.5);
}


/* less bad wind */

.wedge {
  z-index: 10 !important;
}

.wedge:hover {
  fill: rgba(21, 255, 0, 0.5);
}


/* best wind */


/*
* === Arrow ===
*/


/* adjust the center point and make arrow wiggle at all times */

#arrow {
  transform-origin: 50% 59.7%;
  animation-name: wiggle;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forward;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


/*
* === ADD CLASS TO #arrow to move to location and wiggle ===
*/

.north#arrow {
  transform-origin: 50% 59.7%;
  animation-name: spinNorth, wiggleNorth;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s, 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
}

.northEast#arrow {
  transform-origin: 50% 59.7%;
  animation-name: spinNorthEast, wiggleNorthEast;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s, 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
}

.east#arrow {
  transform-origin: 50% 59.7%;
  animation-name: spinEast, wiggleEast;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s, 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
}

.southEast#arrow {
  transform-origin: 50% 59.7%;
  animation-name: spinSouthEast, wiggleSouthEast;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s, 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
}

.south#arrow {
  transform-origin: 50% 59.7%;
  animation-name: spinSouth, wiggleSouth;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s, 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
}

.southWest#arrow {
  transform-origin: 50% 59.7%;
  animation-name: spinSouthWest, wiggleSouthWest;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s, 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
}

.west#arrow {
  transform-origin: 50% 59.7%;
  animation-name: spinWest, wiggleWest;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s, 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
}

.northWest#arrow {
  transform-origin: 50% 59.7%;
  animation-name: spinNorthWest, wiggleNorthWest;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s, 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
}

.wedge:hover {
  fill: rgba(21, 255, 0, 0.5);
}


/*
* === Animations to make #arrow spin ===
*/


/* Spin north Animation */

@keyframes spinNorth {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}


/* Spin  north east Animation */

@keyframes spinNorthEast {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}


/* Spin  east Animation */

@keyframes spinEast {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
}


/* Spin south east Animation */

@keyframes spinSouthEast {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}


/* Spin south Animation */

@keyframes spinSouth {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
}


/* Spin south west Animation */

@keyframes spinSouthWest {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
}


/* Spin west Animation */

@keyframes spinWest {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
}


/* Spin north west Animation */

@keyframes spinNorthWest {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* 360 because this is the starting point of #arrow */
  }
}


/*
* === WIGGLES for each direction ===
*/


/* Wiggle north Animation */

@keyframes wiggleNorth {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(46deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(44deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(46deg);
  }
}


/* Wiggle north east Animation */

@keyframes wiggleNorthEast {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(91deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(89deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(91deg);
  }
}


/* Wiggle  east Animation */

@keyframes wiggleEast {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(136deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(134deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(136deg);
  }
}


/* Wiggle south east Animation */

@keyframes wiggleSouthEast {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(181deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(179deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(181deg);
  }
}


/* Wiggle south Animation */

@keyframes wiggleSouth {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(226deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(224deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(226deg);
  }
}


/* Wiggle south west Animation */

@keyframes wiggleSouthWest {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(271deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(269deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(271deg);
  }
}


/* Wiggle west Animation */

@keyframes wiggleWest {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(316deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(314deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(316deg);
  }
}


/* Wiggle north west Animation */

@keyframes wiggleNorthWest {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(361deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(361deg);
  }
}


/*
* === wiggle when no direction ===
*/

@keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compassWrap">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 116.3 144" style="enable-background:new 0 0 116.3 144;" xml:space="preserve">

<title>compass</title>
<line id="N" class="st0" x1="58.2" y1="31.3" x2="58.2" y2="49.6"/>
<line id="NW" class="st1" x1="18.5" y1="46.1" x2="31.4" y2="59"/>
<line id="W" class="st0" x1="3.6" y1="85.7" x2="21.9" y2="85.7"/>
<line id="SW" class="st1" x1="18.3" y1="125.5" x2="31.3" y2="112.5"/>
<line id="S" class="st0" x1="58" y1="140.3" x2="58" y2="122"/>
<line id="SE" class="st1" x1="97.7" y1="125.6" x2="84.8" y2="112.6"/>
<line id="E" class="st0" x1="113.4" y1="85.9" x2="95.1" y2="85.9"/>
<line id="NE" class="st1" x1="97.8" y1="46.2" x2="84.9" y2="59.1"/>
<path id="compass" class="st2" d="M69.6,28.8c6.7-6.3,7-16.9,0.7-23.6s-16.9-7-23.6-0.7s-7,16.9-0.7,23.6c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.7
 c-31.5,6.3-51.9,37-45.6,68.5s37,51.9,68.5,45.6c31.5-6.3,51.9-37,45.6-68.5C110.6,51.4,92.6,33.4,69.6,28.8z M58.2,6.5
 c5.6,0,10.2,4.6,10.2,10.2H48C48,11.1,52.6,6.5,58.2,6.5z M58.2,138.3c-29,0-52.5-23.5-52.5-52.5s23.5-52.5,52.5-52.5
 c29,0,52.5,23.5,52.5,52.5c0,0,0,0,0,0C110.6,114.8,87.1,138.3,58.2,138.3z"/>
<path id="inner_compass" class="st2" d="M58.2,130.8c-24.9,0-45.2-20.2-45.2-45.2s20.2-45.2,45.2-45.2c24.9,0,45.2,20.2,45.2,45.1
 c0,0,0,0,0,0C103.3,110.6,83.1,130.8,58.2,130.8z M58.2,43.8c-23.1,0-41.9,18.8-41.9,41.9s18.8,41.9,41.9,41.9s41.9-18.8,41.9-41.9
 C100.1,62.6,81.3,43.8,58.2,43.8L58.2,43.8z"/>

<polygon id="arrow" class="st2" points="78.4,105.3 80.2,107.1 79.1,108.3 77.2,106.4 75.5,109.7 74.1,108.6 75.9,105.1 75.1,104.3 
 73.3,107.7 71.9,106.6 73.8,103 72.9,102.1 71.2,105.6 69.8,104.5 71.7,100.9 63.5,92.7 63.5,92.7 41.5,70.7 41.4,70.8 39,74.3 
 34.5,62.5 46.3,67.1 42.5,69.5 64.6,91.6 65.2,92.1 72.9,99.8 76.5,98 77.6,99.5 74.1,101.1 74.9,101.9 78.6,100 79.7,101.4 
 76.2,103.1 75.9,102.9 77.1,104 80.8,102.3 81.9,103.8 "/>

 <path id="nnwPie" class="st4 wedge" d="M57.9,27.7v58.2l-41-41C27.8,33.9,42.5,27.7,57.9,27.7z"/>


 <path id="wnwPie" class="st4 wedge" d="M57.9,85.8H0.2v-0.2c0-15.3,6-30,16.8-40.8L57.9,85.8z"/>


 <path id="wswPie" class="st4 wedge" d="M57.9,85.8l-40.8,40.8c-10.8-10.8-16.9-25.5-17-40.8H57.9z"/>


 <path id="sswPie" class="st4 wedge" d="M57.9,85.8v57.8c-15.3,0-30-6.2-40.8-17L57.9,85.8z"/>


 <path id="ssePie" class="st4 wedge" d="M99,126.9c-10.8,10.8-25.5,16.8-40.8,16.8H58V85.8L99,126.9z"/>


 <path id="esePie" class="st4 wedge" d="M116.2,85.8c0,15.4-6.2,30.2-17.2,41l-41-41H116.2z"/>


 <path id="enePie" class="st4 wedge" d="M116.2,85.7v0.2H57.9l41.2-41.2C110.1,55.5,116.2,70.3,116.2,85.7z"/>


 <path id="nnePie" class="st4 wedge" d="M99.1,44.6L57.9,85.8V27.7h0.2C73.5,27.6,88.3,33.7,99.1,44.6z"/>

</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, and don't forget to accept the solution the worked for you!